# Correct way to resolve a one-to-one relation in a repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a one-to-one relation between pen and license, now I want to find in the LicenseRepository a license by an attribute of a pen for example the serial. How do I have to define this in the repository, my approach was to 
try it with named queries but when I call the findBySerial(String serial) method in the LicenseRepository there is an exception that there is no serial attribute in the LicenseEntity, thats correct but it is in the PenEntity 
which is in the LicenseEntity. I though that spring boot does some vodoo an recognize that there is a PenEntity an this contains a serial attribute. What is the correct way to implement this with spring boot?

```
    @Repository("LicenseRepository")
    public interface LicenseRepository
            extends JpaRepository<LicenseEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<LicenseEntity> {

        LicenseEntity findBySerial(String serial);
        LicenseEntity findByPenId(String penId);

    }



    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "License")
    public class LicenseEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "uid")
        private Long id;

        @Column(nullable = true)
        private String firstUse;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "pen_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid")
        private PenEntity pen;

        public LicenseEntity(PenEntity pen){
            this.pen = pen;
        }


    }


           @AllArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(schema = "epls_dbo", name = "Pen")
    public class PenEntity {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "uid", nullable = false, unique = true)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "penid", nullable = false, unique = true)
        private Long penId;

        @Column(name = "penPassword")
        private String penPassword;

        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean(Types#BIT)")
        boolean userLocked;

        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean(Types#BIT)")
        boolean adminLocked;

        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean(Types#BIT)")
        boolean gplsAccess;

        @Column( columnDefinition = "boolean(Types#BIT)")
        boolean defaultPkpAccess;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        int maxUpdateCounter;

        @Column
        byte[] symmetricKey;

        @Column
        String comment;

        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean(Types#BIT)")
        boolean justActivated;

        @Column
        byte[] activationKey;

        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "penactivationstatus(Types#INTEGER)")
        int activationStatus;

        @Column(name = "serial", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "nvarchar(Types#NVARCHAR)")
        private String serial;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        PenHardware hardware;

        @Transient
        String firstUsage;


    }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing anything the PenEntity you've posted doesn't contain any `serial` attribute. Also wouldn't the correct tag be spring-data instead of spring-boot?

Comment: You are right, my fault, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
List<LicenseEntity> findByPenSerial(String serial)
```

or

```
List<LicenseEntity> findByPen_Serial(String serial)
```

for reference [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Comment: you mean findByPenSerial